# remove uncommon values in php array

Tags: php

Hello all,

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 242) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 24) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 234) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 244) 
)


Array ( 
    [0] => 24
    [1] => 242
    [2] => 244
)
```

When I used `print_r()`, I got above two arrays. Now, I need to filter two arrays and get uncommon values so my output will be 234

Answer (score 5):

I would guess you mean [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff), which returns you the set of elements that only exists in one of the arrays. You might have to run it twice however, if you don't know which array is the superset:

```
$diff = array_merge(array_diff($a1, $a2), array_diff($a2, $a1));
```

Oh and if the first array is nested like that, convert it first into a value list with `$a1 = array_map("current", $a1)` or something.

Answer (score 1):

do a a `foreach` to go through the array, and then use something like `in_array` to do a test to see if any of the keys within the first array exists

```
$array3 = array();
foreach ($array1 as $v)
{
    if !(in_array($v['ID'], $array2))
    {
        $array3[] = $v;
    }
}
$array3 = array_unique($array3);
```

`$array3` will return a list of non existant ID's (that didn't exist in `$array2`)

Answer (score 0):

create two arrays with simply all the values in them, and then do

```
$arrayResult = $array1;
foreach($array1 as $id => $val) {
    if !isset($array2[$id]) {
        $arrayResult[] = $id;
    }
}
foreach($array2 as $id => $val) {
    if !isset($array1[$id]) {
        $arrayResult[] = $id;
    }
}
```

and then $arrayResult will have all uncommon values!